# PostgresDB - Updating a Table from a different Server

Tags: postgresql, database-design, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have a Database on a server (*external*) that has multiple tables that I have a connection to.

I have created a select query that does various joins and that gives me the desired final view of this data. (I have been working with a Temporary Table for testing purposes)

The next step is how do I connect this select query to a Table in a different (*local*) server?

In a nutshell:

- How to write a script that reads a select query pointing to a different server.database.schema and write it in my local server.database.schema.table

**Bonus Question**

Once I get it actually creating/updating/inserting how do I schedule this to be done on a schedule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dblink, or [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).  Or you could just use a pipeline of two `psql` invocations with one doing COPY...TO STDOUT and one doing COPY...FROM STDIN.

If it were a one-time thing, I'd use the last of those, but since it is apparently recurring I would probably use one of the first two.  Postgres_fdw is syntactically nicer, but is also prone to planner problems in a case like this.  You could address that either by using dblink instead, or by creating a view on the foreign side and use postgres_fdw over that view.

Answer (score 0):

**-- Got it working --**

Below is the script that worked for me.

```
truncate "Database"."Table";

insert into "Database"."Table"

select *
from "Database".dblink(
    'host=hostname 
    dbname=hostdatabase 
    user=**** 
    password=**** 
    port=****',
'SELECT *MY SELECT QUERY*;'
)
as t1(*Output Columns*)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING  (Actually unsure if this does anything idk)     
;
```